# jquery ajax pagemethod not working

Tags: html, ajax, json, jquery

I'm using page method to retrieve login information. My code goes as follows,

```
 $.ajax( {
  type: "POST",
  url: Main.url + loginBox.url  ,
  data: '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "login", "params": {"login": "'+nameVal+'", "pass": "'+passVal+'"'+ ( loginBox.userSaveUdid ? ","id": 1}',
  async: true,
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  beforeSend: function(){
    alert("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------loginBox.submit : beforeSend");
    $("#login-error").html();
    Loading.show();
  },
  success: function(data) {

    alert("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------loginBox.submit : success = ");

    if( data.error ){

      $("#login-error").html(data.error.message)

    }else{

      loginBox.LogInSuccess(nameVal,data.result.user_id,data.result.token)

      /*
      loginBox.userName = nameVal;
      loginBox.userLogged = data.result.user_id;
      loginBox.userToken = data.result.token;
      Limit.getLimit();
      loginBox.hide();
      */
    }


  },
  complete: function(){
    alert("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------loginBox.submit : complete");
    Loading.hide();
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
    $("#login-error").html(textStatus)
    alert("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------loginBox.submit : error " +textStatus);
  }
});
```

I'm getting 404 Not page found error. I used firebug to check those and request and responses.

this what i got.

> Response Headersview

Via 1.1 BILEETAISA

Connection  Keep-Alive

Proxy-Connection    Keep-Alive

Content-Length  728

Date    Wed, 27 Jul 2011 22:17:53 GMT

Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8

Server  Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)

X-Powered-By    Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.7

X-Runtime   0.004490

Status  404

Request Headersview

Host    xxxx.tv

User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate

Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7

Proxy-Connection    keep-alive

Origin  null

Access-Control-Request-Me...    POST

Access-Control-Request-He...    content-type

Pragma  no-cache

Cache-Control   no-cache

Can someone tell me where is the fault. Is it should be accept field in request header as application/json? Should i add to json library to my project also? Isn't that enough with only jquery. Pardon me if this is dumb question. I'm newer to this stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Home.aspx")%>'
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: pageUrl + '/UpdateWlcomMessage',
                  data: '{WelcomeText: "' + welocmetext + '"}',
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (data) {
                  }
              });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it as pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/xxx.tv")%> But i got Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "file:.../javascript/jquery.js Line: 7869"]. BTW i'm not using asp.net or something like that. Just only javascript and html. Have you any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL for correct

url: Main.url + loginBox.url

First copy past your correct page URL and method name . then check please  .

For sample is

```
 var pageUrl = 'Contact.aspx';
        $.ajax({
            url: pageUrl + '/SendMail',
            type: "POST",
            data: '{Name: "' + Name + '",FromEmail: "' + FromEmail + '",Body: "' + Body + '"}',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d == 1) {
                    $("input[type=button]").val("Send Mail");
                    alert("Mail successfully sent");
                    $('#envelope').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#fade').css('display', 'none');

                }
            }
        });
```